# What is the meaning of screenSurface->format in SDL?

Tags: c++, sdl

I have recently started studying SDL and I would like to get a good understanding of it. I have followed Lazy Foo' Productions' tutorials and there is one statement that I don't get. What is the meaning behind the `gScreenSurface->format` or `screenSurface->format` in the examples below?

```cpp
SDL_ConvertSurface( screenSurface, gScreenSurface->format, 0 );
```

```cpp
SDL_FillRect( screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB( screenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF ));
```

Hope someone can explain it, brief explanation needed only. Thanks!

Comment: What didn't you undersant from the [SDL Documentstion](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_Surface)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the [documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_ConvertSurface)? The format is an SDL Pixel Format detailing how the pixels are set in memory.

Comment: Thanks, I was a bit stuck with that for a while. Now I see it's a basic thing.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are asking, but `gScreenSurface->format` means "dereference the pointer in `gScreenSurface` to get the value `format` in whatever it points to". What's not clear about that? That's basic pointer use.